# How to jump from do to end of a Ruby block using Vim?

Tags: ruby, vim

I'm using vim for ruby, php and perl development. There is the shortcut <kbd>%</kbd> to jump from the begin of a block (subroutine/function/method/if) to the end and vice versa.
For me a <kbd>%</kbd> on a do/end tag in ruby doesn't work.

How can I do that with vim?

Comment: % jumps to the matching bracket or brace, that's why it doesn't work in ruby. Still a good question, my guess would to hitchhike on the syntax/folding expressions, but I have no real clue... :)

Comment: Please see the accepted answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067876/vim-and-ruby-matching-dos-and-ends
This lets you use `%` for jumping between do-end without having to install any additional plugins.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [matchit plugin](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/vim-plugins-matchit-vim/) allows matching more than just parentheses and comments. A ruby version can be found [here](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=290).

Comment: the plugin is great, also very helpful for HTML tags. 
With do and end I have a problem. I can jump from end -> do, but I can't jump from this postion return to end, because do isn't on the beginning of the line I think.

Comment: Note that with more recent versions of Vim, matchit is included by default, and as far as I can tell, ruby-matchit.vim just breaks things. Don't install a thing. All you want is the following in your .vimrc (it's not enabled by default because of compatibility issues): `runtime macros/matchit.vim`

Comment: If someone's using [Vundle] (https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim), just add `Bundle 'vim-scripts\matchit.zip'` to your .vimrc and run BundleInstall.

Answer (score 7):

with the [matchit plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) and this code in ~/.vim/ftplugin/ruby.vim it works now :)

```
" Matchit support:
if exists("loaded_matchit")
  if !exists("b:match_words")
    let b:match_ignorecase = 0
    let b:match_words =
\ '\%(\%(\%(^\|[;=]\)\s*\)\@<=\%(class\|module\|while\|begin\|until\|for\|if\|unless\|def\|case\)\|\<do\)\>:' .
\ '\<\%(else\|elsif\|ensure\|rescue\|when\)\>:\%(^\|[^.]\)\@<=\<end\>'
  endif
endif
```