# Vim and Ruby - matching "do"s and "end"s?

Tags: ruby, vim

I'm sure we're all familiar with the "unexpected kEnd" problem. They are always (to me) a lot of trouble to track down, because Vim doesn't match "do"s and "end"s. (And, obviously, other elements that end with "end", like "if")

Is there a way to configure Vim to show these matches to help make debugging easier?

Comment: Proper indentation might help.

Comment: It does help, and all my files are perfectly well-indented. It doesn't help enough, though, especially one that nested indenting starts getting awfully deep... (and when the problem wasn't improper indenting, but the fact that you missed putting in a do at the beginning of your block)

Comment: Use [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic).

Comment: This answer helped me - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1629883/1291712

Answer (score 26):

If you are using a recent vim (I'm using 7.4), the built-in matchit macro works well with ruby code.

Simply enable it by adding the following to your .vimrc

```
runtime macros/matchit.vim
```

Hit % to match do/end combos and many others in ruby files.

Comment: Didn't realise this was built in! Great. Also works with `def` / `end`

Comment: Works with neovim as well!

Answer (score 5):

I use [this macro](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=290) and then add this to my vimrc to enable it:

```
" % to bounce from do to end etc.
runtime! macros/matchit.vim
```

When I want to find the matching end for a do, I cursor over the do and hit %.

Comment: Hmm... while this is exactly what I'm looking for by description, it doesn't actually seem to /work/. It just jumps to the beginning of the line. Strange. No, wait... ah, it works for ifs, and it works going /backwards/ from "end"s, but I can't get it to work going forward from "do"s.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't even seem to be matching ruby syntax at all - it's just matching indent levels. Since I use foldmethod=indent, this is... fairly useless. It certainly doesn't help me track down bugs. Sorry, its a good idea, but this implementation is definitely lacking. :/

Comment: Works for me in all the cases you are reporting problems with. It's possible I got my macro from a different source - let me see if I can track it down.

Comment: From the comments in the actual file: "This function isn't very sophisticated. It just takes care of indentation. If you're on the line `if x', then the cursor will jump to the next line with the same indentation as the if-clause." So that seems to explain the behaviour. If you've got a different (better) version, I'd love to see it! ^_^

Answer (score 4):

"endwise" is a pretty nice vim extension that adds them automatically, which I found greatly reduces the amount of missing `end`s. etc:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2386

Comment: I use this too, but occasionally forget it's already been added and add it myself. Then I'm lost in a sea of do/end, which is where matchit comes in.

Answer (score -2):

I use [this](https://github.com/tsaleh/vim-matchit) matchit clone, that can be installed easily with [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle).